# How to get All files Name in Public Directory in Android 11+?

Tags: java, android

I have not getting Files which created without my App means Another Files which not created by my Application...

```
folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/" + "com.krunaldhoriya.stockmanager");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
            files = folder.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,files[i].getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

It not Display by Any other files which not created by my Application...
So How to i get All files of this directory which it have already ?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply for relevant permission.

Comment: I also added write external storage and read external storage but it still not getting any files in toast message.

Only Application created files will shown in this toast

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it possible that there are no files under your application package